# SQL Server x10 Quantity check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with Article_code, Date, And Quantity.

What I try is to find where for the same article the quantity had an increase or a decrease of 10 times compared to the previous date.

For instance, I have following columns

```
Article  Date Quantity X10     
1001     20-01-2015 22    
1001    21-02-2016 220
```

For the row with quantity 220 should be marked as x in column x10.

What I tried is the following

```
UPDATE ph
SET [X10] = 'Px10'
FROM 
    [dbo].[Sales] ph 
    inner join [dbo].[Sales] t on (ph.[Article] = t.[Article]) 
WHERE
    ph.[quantity] / t.[quantity] = 10
    OR
    t.[quantity] / ph.[quantity] = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select *,
case when exists
(
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where dateadd(day,-1,t1.[Date])=t2.[Date]
    and t1.Quantity>=10*t2.Quantity
) then 'x' else '' end as 'x10'
from youttable t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE s
SET    s.x10 = 'x'
FROM   Sales s
       OUTER APPLY (   SELECT   TOP 1 quantity
                       FROM     sales s2
                       WHERE    s2.Article_code = s.Article_code
                                AND s2.date < s.date
                       ORDER BY s2.date DESC ) t
WHERE  s.quantity = 10 * t.quantity;
```